# pdb causing pyreadline unicode_helper error

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'm trying the following code. It produces an error. If I run it without pdb, it works fine. I'm baffled by this because pdb was working fine yesterday. I'm running a python 2.7 virtual environment from Anaconda. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
import pdb

def main():
    pdb.set_trace()
    print "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test_code.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_code.py", line 5, in main
    print "hello world"
  File "test_code.py", line 5, in main
    print "hello world"
  File "D:\Users\Tom\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\bdb.py", line 67, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\pdb.py", line 158, in user_line
    self.interaction(frame, None)
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\pdb.py", line 210, in interaction
    self.cmdloop()
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\cmd.py", line 112, in cmdloop
    import readline
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import unicode_helper, logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .console import *
  File "...\Anaconda\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pyreadline.unicode_helper as unicode_helper
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unicode_helper'
```

Comment: Issue resolved by reinstalling my Python 2.7 virtual enviroment. Still not sure what was wrong, suspect it was a conflict between line_profiler and pdb.

Comment: Issue resolved by reinstalling pyreadline